# How to loop through JSON object retrieved via Http Angular 2/ Typescript

Tags: json, angular, http, typescript

I'm trying to fetch some specific data from my JSON file via http. JSON looks like this:

```
[{"name":"Name1","perc":33},{"name":"Name2","perc":22},{"name":"Name3","perc":41}]
```

I'm trying to loop through this retrieved object, I'm retrieving it like so:

```
  this._postService.getParams(_url).subscribe(
  data => {
    this.results = data.Results
  },
  error => console.log(error),
  () => console.log('Done')
  );
```

getParams() fetches the data like this

```
    getParams(url: string) {
    return this._http.get(url)
        .map(res => res.json());
}
```

I made an interface for data retrieved, placed it in the same .component.ts file where the service is being called

```
/*Interface for Stats */
interface stats {
name: string;
percent: number;
}
```

I plan to loop through the object I retrieved and store them in a local array and then loop through that and display them. How can I iterate through the JSON object in my component file? I tried many different for loops and they all failed.

I attempted this one and it failed, json was not being recognized by typescript

```
let list: string[] = [];
json.Results.forEach(element => {
list.push(element.Id);
});
```

I'm perfectly able to retrieve the data, because I console logged the 3 objects I received.

Comment: What is the error you receive? Is the json response mentioned on second line result of `console.log(data)` or `console.log(data.results)`?

Comment: Additionally I don't see your code mentioning `json` anywhere. Could it be you are using keyword instead of `this.results`?

Comment: The error is simply ts: Cannot find json

Comment: Then `json` is not defined as parameter. Use this.results instead.

Comment: where exactly are you trying to loop this?

Answer (score 0):

Class stats :

```
export class Stats {
    name: string;
    perc: string;
    constructor(n, p) {
        this.name = n;
        this.perc = p;
    }
}
```

Assuming your service works and returns data, don't change it.

Component :

```
getStats(_url: string) {
    let list: Stats[] = [];
    this._postService.getParams(_url).subscribe(
        data => {
            for (let res of data.Results) {
                let stat = new Stats(res.name, res.perc);
                list.push(stat);
            }
        }, err => { /* Error handling */}
    );
}
```

Comment: Because you need to create instances of this class, and you can't do it with an interface. You can either replace your interface with that, or yes, you can put it in the file of your choice. If it's not in the same file as your component, just remember to import it !

Comment: Yeah figured it out, trying it now.

Comment: I tested out your solution, but now I'm getting an error:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: Funny, because nowhere in my code I can read a `length` property. Maybe you could resolve it yourself by looking at the error, or at least post your code ?

Answer (score 0):

You assigned received data on this.results

```
this.results = data.Results
```

But then trying to go through `json.Results`

Replace `json.Results` on `this.results`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to simply cast the data into your array:

```
getParams(url: string) {
  return this._http.get(url)
    .map(res => <stats[]> res.json());
}
```

Then in this code:

```
  this._postService.getParams(_url).subscribe(
  data => {
    this.results = data.Results
  },
  error => console.log(error),
  () => console.log('Done')
  );
```

`this.results` should be your array of stats.